# How to check if current url in list of urlpatterns?

Tags: django, django-urls

I am a bit puzzled. I want to check if the current url of the website is in a specific subset of my urlpatters. Which function of django would do this? This is for a middleware that requests additional information before moving to a specific part of my website.

```
class AuthorityMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        current_url = request.path_info
        if not request.user.is_anonymous() and current_url not in exclude_list:
            if not request.session.get('authority'):
                return get_the_authority(request)
```

How should exclude list relate to the urlpatterns defined in urls.py?

Comment: The [`resolve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve) method takes a url path and returns the corresponding view, but it's not clear whether that's what you want. Your question would be clearer if you gave some examples of the views and url patterns that you want to exclude. Are you sure you want this check in middleware, and not a decorator for restricted views?

Comment: I checked the resolve, but I only want a subset of the urls defined in my urlpattern, e.g. specific apps, that are public, and others that need an additional login. You are right with the decorator. I was thinking the wrong thing all the time. Back in the time when I created the above code, I was thinking that middlewares are the only place where you could redirect to another page before your view is shown. But that is not true. I was able to resolve my problem with a proper decorator. Thank you.

Comment: my exclude list had a list of reverse functions and urls, but they would fail for urls that require further parameters, like tokenized functions, and functions that require keys (password reset, etc.).

Comment: Sounds like a decorator is a better approach. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my issue basically is the result of bad design. The whole issue can be solved if I use decorators to ask for the authority for the views that require it. Back when I wrote the above code I was thinking that middlewares would be the only place to redirect and call further functions before a view is shown, but in fact they are good to apply a function to all your views. Decorators are better if the functions only apply to a subset of views.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


def project_required(func):
    def decorated(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.session.get('authority'):
            request.session['previous_url'] = resolve(request.path_info).url_name
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('project_login'))
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```